# Call Tomcat Instance from Android Device in local Network (WLAN)

Tags: java, android, tomcat, wifi

I have a very confusing problem, accessing my Tomcat from an Android Device in my Local WLAN.

**Situation:**

On my DesktopPC (Internal LAN IP: 192.168.1.100) I have running a Tomcat Application Server with a JSF Site.

The entry URL is **192.168.1.100:8080/pages/index.jsf**

If I try now to call this Site from my Android Device (also connected to the WLAN) I get the typical "Site not found"-Page in the Android Browser.

I can call the Site from any other PC in my Home-Network with the given URL.

Can anyone give me a hint, how to call the JSF_Site from Android, please?

I have tried the following URL´s with no effort:

- **192.168.1.100:8080/pages/index.jsf**
- .**http://192.168.1.100:8080/pages/index.jsf**

**EDIT:**

Tried it with an Emulator on the same Machine and it works with the given URL.

**EDIT2:**

I tried the URL with Android Fling and got the following output. Probably anyone can read anything from it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a terminal emulator on your android device? Try to ping the address. I presume you use wifi with your device. Have you used a laptop with wifi too? This could be good to rule out your home router as a possible cause.

Have you visited webs like myip to verify that you are using the same external ip. This could be good to rule out other internet connections in case you have a 3G internet connection or similar.

Have you tried with an static html file instead of a jsf. Is there some jsf tag which is redirecting you when you use small screen devices?

Your screen shoot displays port 80 as your port. Perhaps you are not getting the right url or there is a restriction on your device. You can change the tomcat port in the server.xml file
look for the following like and change 8080 for 80 as it is here... My tomcat is 6.x

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

You are getting a ->HTTP 400 Bad request according to the RFC your browser is not forming the request properly. Perhaps you should try another browser such us Firefox for android.

I hope my tips can help you.

Regards

Comment: Hi PbxMan, thank you for your Tips. I have pinged my Computer from the Android Devices (only the IP) and there seems no problem. That means, there is a connection established between my Android and my PC. I tried to open the URL with Firefox, with the same bad result. Trieng the other Tips now.

Comment: I checked my external IP and tried this, ending up on the startpage of my Router. But thats normal I believe.

Comment: Changed the Port from 8080 to 80 and disabled Microsoft IIS (old stuff from Visual Studio), called 192.168.1.100/pages/index.jsf (now with only html page in it), same bad result

Comment: Ok, damn, i found the failure. Finally my Windows Firewall blocks content. Switched it off and now it works.